# Parse and manipulate date times with micro seconds

Tags: javascript

I have date time strings with the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS`

For example:

```
const d1 = '2022-07-03 03:45:15.679570'
const d2 = '2022-07-03 03:45:15.679638'
```

What I'd like to achieve is the ability to subtract these date times, e.g. in the above example the result would be:

```js
console.log(subtractDates(d1, d2)) // -0000-00-00 00-00-00.000068
console.log(subtractDates(d2, d1)) // 0000-00-00 00-00-00.000068
```

I was looking for different libraries but they all have resolution of 0-999 ms and that's it.

Comment: Do you need the output to be in date format, or can the output just be a number (e.g., `-68`)?

Comment: Hi Matthew, in date format just because the diff could be not only in ms, but it could be greater (e.g. totalDays could be >0)

Comment: How would you calculate difference in months? This can be ambiguous. Is 2022-03-31 minus 2022-02-28 equal to 0000-01-00 or 0000-01-03? What if both input dates move by one day back, what if both dates move by one day forward?

Comment: let me define better the return of the desired function, the format would be TotalYears difference as YYYY, then totalMonths difference in MM and so on.. Otherwise I agree with you about the ambiguously represent time.

Comment: So how do you want it, for what concerns month differences? A solution would be to not go beyond the day level, and keep counting differences that are larger in terms of days, never months or years (also ambiguous -- think of leap years ).

Comment: Trincot, take for example current implementation without what I request - even with 2 months which different days amount, when you subtract them you can get the delta between the dates. I don't mind to get the this total amount as milliseconds or microseconds and I'll calculate the days/months/years according to that.

Comment: I didn't understand what you wrote about the delta and how it answers my question. I have posted an answer with the idea I expressed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtraction of dates becomes ambiguous when months are subtracted. For instance, there are several possibilities on how to represent the difference between 2022-03-31 and 2022-02-28. If this is considered to be a difference of 1 months and 3 days, then what if we add one day to both dates? Is then the difference (of the same number of days) suddenly an exact month?

To avoid this ambiguity, I would suggest to express the difference in a number of days (and smaller units of time) even when that number of days exceeds a month or even a year. Just keep the greatest unit of measure to the day when dealing with *durations*.

Here is a pair of classes that could easily be extended to provide more functionality. The general idea is to use the numeric system of the native `Date` type, but to multiply it by 1000.

```js
class MicroDuration {
    constructor(us) {
        this.us = Math.abs(us); // Don't work with negative durations.
    }
    toString() { // dddddd hh:mm:ss.ssssss
        return (Math.floor(this.us / 86_400_000_000) + " " 
                + new Date(Math.floor(this.us / 1000)).toJSON().slice(11, 23) 
                + (this.us % 1000 + "").padStart(3, "0")
               ).padStart(22, "0");
    }
}

class MicroDate {
    constructor(iso) {
        iso = iso.replace(" ", "T").replace(/\d$/, "$&Z");
        this.us = Date.parse(iso) * 1000 + parseInt(iso.slice(-4));
    }
    diff(arg) {
        if (!(arg instanceof MicroDate)) arg = new MicroDate(arg);
        return new MicroDuration(this.us - arg.us);
    }
    toString() {
        return new Date(Math.floor(this.us / 1000)).toJSON()
                .replace("Z", (this.us % 1000 + "").padStart(3, "0"))
                .replace("T", " "); 
    }
}

// Demo
const d1 = '2022-07-03 03:45:15.679570'
const d2 = '2024-08-03 15:45:15.678638'
const diff = new MicroDate(d1).diff(d2).toString();
console.log(diff);
```